# Arduino double clap sensing code breaking

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am making a program that turns my lights on when I clap twice. I coded the project to:
1. listen for a noise (first clap)
2. listen for quiet (break between claps) this is to avoid false triggers (talking, etc.).
3. listen for a second noise (second clap).

The code runs through and works properly, but it has several breaking points that I am struggling to find/fix. I know if I make a noise, then I am quiet, then I make another noise repeatedly, and in rapid succession the code either gets stuck in the first while loop, or stops entering the first while loop altogether. The code often breaks when I am talking.

I have provided the code if anybody is willing to spare me some of there time and effort. I will be appreciative of all suggestions as I am still a beginner.

```
bool quiet = false;
bool loud = false;
int runtime = 1000;
int start = millis();
bool clap = false;
bool clap2 = false;
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    int mic = digitalRead(2);
    if (mic == 0) {
        Serial.println("loud");
        clap = true;
    } else {
        Serial.println("quiet");
    }
    if (clap == true) {
        clap = false;
        Serial.println("clap");
        start = millis();
        delay(500);
        while (start >= millis() - runtime && loud != true) {
            mic = digitalRead(2);
            if (mic == 0) {
                Serial.println("noise detected!");
                loud = true;
            } else {
                Serial.println("scilence");
                quiet = true;
            }

        }
    } else {
        delay(1);
    }
    if (quiet == true && loud == false) {
        quiet = false;
        Serial.println("listening for second clap...");
        delay(500);
        start = millis();
        while (start >= millis() - runtime) {
            mic = digitalRead(2);
            if (mic == 0) {
                clap2 = true;
            } else {
                delay(1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        loud = false;
        quiet = false;
    }
    if (clap2 == true) {
        clap2 = false;
        Serial.println("clap 2");
        delay(1000);
    } else {
        delay(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

From the program you posted I think you are over-complicating it ;). First of all, the `delay()` function is a blocking function: nothing can happen during the lapse of time of the delay. Thus it is usually advise to compare times in order to know if you have waited enough: you can then perform other tasks in the meantime.

I would propose something like this for your `loop()` function:

```
if(digitalRead(2)==0) //loud
{
    unsigned long first_clap_time = millis();
    unsigned long elapsed_time = 0;
    bool silence = false;
    bool exit = false;
    while (elapsed_time < 5000 || exit)  // allow a max delay of 5sec
    {
        if (digitalRead(2)!=0) silence = true;
        elapsed_time = millis() - first_clap_time;
        if (digitalRead(2)==0 && elapsed_time > 500 && silence) 
        {
            Serial.println("Two claps detected!");  //if a second clap is detected 500 milliseconds after the first, and before 5 sec, and a silence was detected
            exit = true;
        }
    }      
}
```

This should be able to detect only two claps, separated by a time between 500 milliseconds and 5 seconds (to adjust of course). I have no way to test this program so do not hesitate to provide feedback!

Hope it helps,

Comment: Your code works perfectly, and I think I understand what you are saying about comparing times instead of using the delay function. I will definitely use that information in the future!  The only problem is I need the code to detect a clap, then make sure the surroundings are quiet, then detect another clap. I found that if I can make the code detect silence before the second clap, I can avoid a majority of false triggers like talking. 

Do you think that this is possible to do?

Comment: I am happy to hear that! I edited my answer to wait for a silence to be detected before trigerring a second clap (I did not see this requirements at the first glance). Note that it will event works for a very brief silence… But the modifications for a quite long silence are not heavy!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You really helped me out, but I am expierencing an issue. The program works as needed until I get to the end where it will run the if statement mulitple times making the serial look like this:
```first clapTwo claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
Two claps detected!
```
I tried to make the program run once by adding the statement:

Comment: Is it a success?